# não permitir selecionar domingos com PHP

Tags: php, html

Estou a escrever um formulário em html e php para que o utilizador possa escolher uma data para marcar, no entanto não queria que o utilizador escolhesse domingos.

```
 <input type="datetime-local" id="datetime" name="datetime" value="<?php echo $current_date; ?>" min="<?php echo $current_date; ?>T10:00" max="T17:30" step="900" required><br><br>
```

como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente, não é possível restringir diretamente a escolha de dias específicos com o elemento HTML "datetime-local".

### Aqui esta uma solução que pode solucionar esse problema

Como seu input esta dentro de um formulário, você pode usar `$_POST['submit']` é uma variável associativa do PHP que representa o valor do botão de envio de um formulário HTML.
Depois você pode usar a função `date` do PHP para verificar o dia da semana do valor escolhido pelo usuário e validar se não é domingo.

exemplo

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //verifica se o formulario foi enviado
    $selectedDate = $_POST['datetime']; 
    $dayOfWeek = date('w', strtotime($selectedDate));

    if ($dayOfWeek == 0) {
        echo '<script>alert('Por favor, selecione outra data que não seja domingo.');</script>';
    } else {
        // Processar o formulário
    }
}
```

Na variavel `$dayOfWeek` esta sendo para validar o dia da semana 0 para domingo, 1 para segunda-feira, etc...

Comment: usei javascript e o flatpickr e depois nas configuraçoes do mesmo usei um função dentro do disable e funcionou, obrigada na mesma!